# Dynamic expression columns creation on C# DataTable results in memory crash

Tags: c#, windows, csv, memory, datatable

I have a DataTable based on CSV file in C# (~50 columns, ~20,000 rows), which then for I create dynamically about 800000 expression based columns with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-expression-columns) method. Result is Single based - float - 4 bytes.

for each of the dynamically created columns, I create another 8 expression based columns. (overall
6,400,000) columns.

```
800000*8*20000*4 = 512,000,000,000 bytes = 512 Gigabytes.
expressions*cols*rows*bytes = total assumed memory
```

I am working on windows 10 with 64GB memory, 1TB SSD and automatic page file settings.
My memory is filled pretty quickly and then being lowered a bit and after about 1 hour of calculations the PC starts to make jitters on the screen and the program crash with an error of some kind about memory stuff.

The page file maximum consumption is 3 times the physical memory so

```
64*4 = 256 Gigabytes.
```

Still insufficient for my purpose.

I have tried adding `GC.Collect();` statements but it didn't help. :(

Any creative ideas on this issue?
Thanks :)

Comment: You've explained what you're doing, but can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish with this many columns? What's the point? It would be good to get some more context to understand which ideas to propose.

Comment: Sure, its an offline brute force. each cell is a number, I create all of the possible formulas for all of the cols and mathematical operations, such as:
[Col1 * Col2]
[Col1 - Col2]
[Col2 / Col1]
etc...
it works for 2 columns as this example, but when I try 3 columns and 2 math operations the problem starts happenning.

Comment: You need to change your algorithm to compensate for not being able to load everything into memory at one.  Is it possible you could perhaps run calculations on 10,000 rows at a time

Comment: The entire calculations has to be saved and used in real time afterwards :|

Comment: Can the calculations be used as they are generated? So, say, you calculate 500 rows, use them, then you calculate the next 500 rows, and so on.

Comment: mmm no, I can delete the first created expression column after the creation of the extra 8 columns. might help with memory consumption no? like ~10%

Comment: It all went wrong for me at the point where you said you tried making 800,000 columns on a datatable, each of which has an `.Expression`

Comment: That you're trying to build a full rainbow table(?) in memory is probably not helping you. Consider creating rows in some form of DB instead and just fill in the data row-by-row. Could be a SQLite DB. This is instead of using `DataTable`.